# Is there a single-tab layout in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I ditch multi-tab layout in Visual Studio and just use a single editor for all work within a solution?

i.e.: 1 solution window has only 1 code editor. Opening a new file just opens it in the same editor.

(I'm running VS 2019 if that matters)

Comment: Suppose editor does show only one file. You change the file, but do not save the changes, and then open another file. What would you expect to happen with the first file? Should the editor just keep the file open, but not show the tab, or should the editor ask you to save the file, or should the editor automatically save the file, or should the editor discard all changes?

Answer (score 1):

Found an extension that seems to work for VS 2019 16.11.5:

[Hide Main Menu, Title Bar, and Tabs extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Poma.MinimalisticView&ssr=false#overview)

This extension is not officially updated to support VS 2022, but you can install it manually. You can find a .vsix package for VS 2022 [here](https://github.com/poma/MinimalisticView/issues/18#issuecomment-1147271415)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to open in window to open new file
goto File -> start window -> choose the one you want

if you want open in same window with different tab
open the file => click on file and then choose float
[image]

Note: you can also group your tabs if required